# Can we authorise Congnito User with POST, PUT, DELETE, GET for API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Can we authorise Congnito User with POST, PUT, DELETE, GET for API Gateway ?

Answer (score 0):

Use GET to authorize see AUTHORIZATION Endpoint manual
[GET /oauth2/authorize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html)